# jQuery Tools: Date Input / Validator Not Working Together

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am using jQuery Tools v1.2.7 and jQuery v1.7.2.  I have the following code:

```
<input type="date" name="delivery_due" required="required">
```

With the following settings:

```
$("form.validate").validator();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":date").dateinput( { format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', min: 0 });
});
```

The validation script always sees the date field as null; even if I have selected a value and that value is displayed within the input field.  It has no issues with any other field with a required attribute; just the date-range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New and improved answer:
Try running `$("form.validate").validator();` *after* the dateinput function. I think this should do the trick.

Old stupid answer:
Try changing `$(":date").dateinput(...` to `$("input[name=delivery_due]").dateinput(...`

Comment: Neither of these solutions on their own worked; I solved the issue by placing date call OUTSIDE of the document.ready.

Comment: Ok, I can see how that helps the timing problem. Thanks for accepting my answer, though.